# SQL Server index on multiple "LIKE @filter + '%'" filters

Tags: sql-server

When creating LIKE filters (I'm doing StartsWith logic, not Contains) do I need to do anything special with the indexes, or just create standard nonclustered index?

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE AccountUID = @AccountUID AND (FirstName LIKE @Filter + '%' OR LastName LIKE @Filter + '%' OR Company LIKE @Filter + '%')
```

Proposed Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Contact_Search] ON [dbo].[Contact]
(
    [AccountUID] ASC,
    [FirstName] ASC,
    [LastName] ASC,
    [Company] ASC
)
```

Comment: Do you really use the same variable `@Filter` to search for `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Company` at the same time ?

Comment: Yes, because it's a general search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing special you need to do with your index. The index you've laid out there looks like it will support your query perfectly.

This probably goes beyond the scope of your question, but here's a little bit to know about indexes and wildcards. As long as your search predicate (the value you're comparing in your where clause) is a known value, you can make use of an index. In your sample, you say `like @filter + '%'` so that's perfectly ok, because it evaluates to (say) "Hello" + anything. The record in the index looks like (again, by example) "Hello World", so it can seek right to it.

You CANT however make use of an index if you start off your search predicate with a wildcard for example `'%' + @filter + '%'`. Now you have a problem because your string could be "AardvarkHello" or "ZebraHello" and it has no idea where to look.

Comment: @Xedni, @MikeCole, The given index doesn't cover the given query. It covers this query: `WHERE AccountUID = @AccountUID AND FirstName = @Filter AND LastName = @Filter AND Company LIKE @Filter + '%'` To cover the given query you need 3 indexes: `(AccountUID, FirstName)`, `(AccountUID, LastName)`, `(AccountUID, CompanyName)`. With original index you'll get index scan (i.e. read all rows), with three indexes you'll get three index seeks concatenated together.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, A covering query is a query in which al the columns being serached and retrieved are included in the index (whether the Key, or via INCLUDE column). YOu dont' need 3 different indices, becaues SQL will only choose the one best suited to the query, which is the one he has. Unless he has SEAPARTE lookup cases which would support the cases you laid out, his index is fine. Please note that your additional index primitives do not "cove" the inedx either.

Comment: @Xedni, I checked the execution plan on SQL Server 2008. With the given index original query uses `index scan`, which means that the server reads all rows, it doesn't **search**. With three separate indexes the optimizer did three `index seeks`, i.e. **searches**. With my test data with only 100K rows with original index there were 1199 logical reads, with three indexes there were 653 reads. @MikeCole, just try both variants with your real data and compare the execution plans and IO. Make sure to try specific searches, i.e `@Filter='Vladimir%'` and broad searches, i.e. `@Filter='V%'`.

Comment: @Xedni, he actually has separate lookup cases. His original query uses `OR`, not `AND`.